# Converting JavaScript to Python APL using Google Earth Engine: image is not defined

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google, google-earth-engine-python-api

I installed geemap on Jupyter Notebook. I converted JavaScript to Python but it keeps show this error:

```
'image' is not defined
```

How can I define an image and writing a function base on it, and then show the map?

Here is my code:

```
import geemap as gm
import ee
import os
import folium
# get ASTER emissivity
aster = ee.Image("NASA/ASTER_GED/AG100_003")

#get ASTER FVC from NDVI
aster_ndvi = aster.select('ndvi').multiply(0.01)

aster_fvc = aster_ndvi.expression('((ndvi-ndvi_bg)/(ndvi_vg - ndvi_bg))**2',
  {'ndvi':aster_ndvi,'ndvi_bg':0.2,'ndvi_vg':0.86})
aster_fvc = aster_fvc.where(aster_fvc.lt(0.0),0.0)
aster_fvc = aster_fvc.where(aster_fvc.gt(1.0),1.0)

# bare ground emissivity functions for each band
def exports_emiss_bare_band10(image):
  return image.expression('(EM - 0.99*fvc)/(1.0-fvc)',{
    'EM':aster.select('emissivity_band10').multiply(0.001),
    'fvc':aster_fvc}) \
    .clip(image.geometry())

Map.addLayer(image)
Map
```

here is the JavaScript code that i convert it to Python:

```
var aster = ee.Image("NASA/ASTER_GED/AG100_003")

//get ASTER FVC from NDVI
var aster_ndvi = aster.select('ndvi').multiply(0.01);

var aster_fvc = aster_ndvi.expression('((ndvi-ndvi_bg)/(ndvi_vg - ndvi_bg))**2',
  {'ndvi':aster_ndvi,'ndvi_bg':0.2,'ndvi_vg':0.86});
aster_fvc = aster_fvc.where(aster_fvc.lt(0.0),0.0);
aster_fvc = aster_fvc.where(aster_fvc.gt(1.0),1.0);
    
// bare ground emissivity functions for each band
exports.emiss_bare_band10 = function(image){
  return image.expression('(EM - 0.99*fvc)/(1.0-fvc)',{
    'EM':aster.select('emissivity_band10').multiply(0.001),
    'fvc':aster_fvc})
    .clip(image.geometry())
};
```

Comment: How do you call `exports_emiss_bare_band10`? Please add the line calling the method?

Comment: actually didnt call it,its just a name of function .while i was converting,i had an error on dote between exports and emiss ,so i changed it to _ instead of .

Comment: What is the line throwing the error in your Python code? `image`  is in the function and normally you don't get any error without calling the function.

Comment: the error is:   NameError: name 'image' is not defined

Comment: when i try to show this map with Map.addLayer(image) at the end of the code...this error occurred

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're running Earth Engine stuff outside of the code editor, you need to initialize the client library because you're probably going to need to provide security credentials. See: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/python_install#package-import

```
import ee
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()
```